# How to enable handwriting panel? (Windows 8 on a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga13)

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

When using my touch keyboard I can not access the handwriting panel. The keyboard comes up properly, I can choose from the standard layout and the thumbs keyboard, but the handwriting panel is not offered as a choice.

(http://windows.microsoft.com/hu-hu/windows-8/using-touch-keyboard  - this video shows four icons to choose from in the case of the touch keyboard. If I click on the selector icon I receive only three...) (From this video - I know it is not a professional source - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGJcldTetA4 I have the idea that what I am missing is possible... :))

Question is simple: how can I turn on the handwriting panel? (Or am I missing something entirely with my configuration/hardware?) 
Currently I am familiarizing myself with a brand new Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 (Intel Core i3, 4GB RAM)

I am running Windows 8 "Core".

Comment: PLS remove then. I am not an expert.

Comment: The product / as far as I think it / is a windows 8 core. And the answer is: the choice of the handwriting panel is only available if a language pack for the handwriting identification of the current language is installed.

Comment: **Be sure to post that as an answer.**

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the choice of the handwriting panel is only available if a language pack for the handwriting identification of the current language is installed.

[Source](https://superuser.com/users/221247/zoltan)